# Make text bold in SQLite

Tags: android, html, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm new to Android I want to make some text bold or italic or insert a new paragraph in Android sqlite database.db 
I know that I can do it using HTML tags but it doesn't show in the app it displays tags instead of bold or italic text. Can anyone help here is my code
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7KpqDyiTdk5cVc0X2t3N3F1WjA/view
I could have pasted it here but stack overflow doesn't let me paste that much code.

Also it would be a huge help if any one can tell me how can I mark some words as favorite and display them in new activity.

Thanks

Comment: Share the code of how are you setting text to view?

Comment: @vishalk I have shared the Google drive Link of my code above

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7KpqDyiTdk5cVc0X2t3N3F1WjA/view

Comment: @Johndoe You have to format the text while setting it in TextView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code in your CustomAdapter

```
word1.setText(Html.fromHtml(dataSet.get(listPosition).getWord()));
meaning1.setText(Html.fromHtml(dataSet.get(listPosition).getMeaning()));
```

Comment: can u tell me how can I mark some words as favorite and display them in new activity. It would be a huge help.
Thanks

Comment: You will have to save new flag into the database against that word. This flag will tell if word is favorite or not. While fetching favorite words only fetch those records, whose flag is set.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to set data using HTML context

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("htmlcontect u want to show "), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE)
```

Answer (score 0):

While setting text in textview use this -

```
yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(yourStrinfFromDb));
```